# Error al pasar un valor al parámetro de una anotación: "Annotation attributes cannot have parameters"

Tags: java, java-ee, annotation

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que una annotación (`@interface`) acepte como parámetros constantes estáticas?

En este caso tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface prueba { 
    String description() default "";
}
```

...y me gustaría poder aplicar un ResourceBundle aquí:

```
@prueba(description = com.prueba.constants.ConstantsStr.STR_PRUEBA_1)
```

...de la siguiente manera:

```
@prueba(description = resourceBundlePrueba.getString(com.prueba.constants.ConstantsStr.STR_PRUEBA_1)
```

Si al método le pongo parámetros, me sale el error:

> Annotation attributes cannot have parameters

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Estoy casi seguro que si intentas implementarlo podrás contestar tu propia pregunta a menos que te hayas encontrado algún problema, en cuyo caso, dinos cuál es el problema y entre todos lo intentaremos resolver.

Comment: Donde estan esas variables constantes y estaticas? Son publicas? Si lo son no necesitas pasarlas como parametros.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Necesito que una implementación de la interface acepte como parámetro una propiedad con resourcebundle.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la implementación de un método de una interface?

Comment: @DavidFerreira si, gracias

Comment: @skw he editado la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: @Alexmaister he editado la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Mucho mejor @Juan. ¿Has intentado hacer la prueba colocando un String literal? -> @prueba(description = "una descripcion")

Comment: @DavidFerreira gracias. Sí, así funciona, cuando no funciona es cuando le aplico el resourceBundle. Me marca el siguiente error: `The value for annotation attribute Keyword.description must be a constant expression`

Comment: Mira la respuesta, eso que intentas hacer no es posible.

Comment: El error te lo dice claro, no se acepta nada que no sea constante.  Puedes optar por crear constantes (final "type" constante = X). O usar enum que no dejan de ser constantes con potencial de clase.

Comment: Los metodos no devulven objetos constantes , si enuns, si quieres asignarle el valor llamando a un metodo este debera devolver un enum para que el compilador te deje asignarlo (no lo he probado).

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, los parámetros de una anotación pueden recibir como valores solo [expresiones constantes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). No puedes llamar a métodos para especificar el valor de un parámetro en una anotación, porque un método (en este caso `resourceBundlePrueba.getString()`) no es una expresión constante.

Entonces este llamado no es posible:

```
@prueba(description = resourceBundlePrueba.getString(com.prueba.constants.ConstantsStr.STR_PRUEBA_1))
```

Sí se pueden usar Nombres cualificados de la forma `NombreTipo.Identificador` que haga referencia a una variable constante, por ejemplo: `ConstantsStr.STR_PRUEBA`.
Asegúrate de que la constante estática `ConstantsStr.STR_PRUEBA` sea `String`, así puedes pasarle el valor directamente:

```
//Esto si es posible, mientras STR_PRUEBA_1 sea String
@prueba(description = ConstantsStr.STR_PRUEBA_1)
```

Comment: Hola David. Perdón por mi mala explicación sobre lo que necesito. He editado la pregunta. Gracias!